# Generic Async Completed method

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, listbox

I have a silverlight page with a listbox and a combobox...

Based on what the user clicks in the list box, I want to populate the dropdownbox.  The completed event is the same for each item in the list box (items include "BaseTypes", "Bays", "Face", etc)

How can I make the completed method generic so I don't have to have one for each call?

```
private void lstEdits_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ServiceCylinderClient obj = new ServiceCylinderClient();
    obj.GetBaysCompleted += new EventHandler<GetBaysCompletedEventArgs>(GetBaysCompleted(this, baysEventArgs));

    string selectedItem = lstEdits.SelectedItem as string;

    switch selectedItem
    {
         case "BaseTypes":
           obj.GetBaseTypesCompleted += new EventHandler<GetBaseTypesCompletedEventArgs>(GetBaysCompleted(this, baysEventArgs));
           obj.getGetBaseTypesAsync();
           break;
        case "Bays":
           obj.GetBaysCompleted += new EventHandler<GetBaysCompletedEventArgs>(GetBaysCompleted(this, baysEventArgs));
           obj.getGetBaysAsync();
           break;
    }
}
```

As it stands now, I will have to have a "completed method" for each call, but since they would all do the same thing (just set the list box items source)..i'd like to make it generic to simplify things.

```
void GetBaseTypesCompleted(object sender, getBaseTypesCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    lstEdits.ItemsSource = e.Result;
}

void GetBaysCompleted(object sender, getBaysCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    lstEdits.ItemsSource = e.Result;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would need to use reflection to read the 'Result' property off the 'CompletedEventArgs' as they do not all come from a base type that exposes 'Result'.

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
lstEdits.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)e.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(e, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it dont have easy solution for this problem,because every completedmethod has different EventArgs for different result.